# could not be able to eliminate error in android

Tags: android

to all I'm working on android and want to use both `RadioGroup` and `CheckBox` in simple app, and I want to use `setOnCheckedChangeListener()` for both but I'm facing error saying that import collides.
My code is :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

RadioGroup radioGroup;
CheckBox checkBox;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
    checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
    radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int option = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            if(option == R.id.radio0){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You Selected Java is Best", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else if(option == R.id.radio1){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You Selected C++ is Best", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You Selected C# is Best", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });

    checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(isChecked){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You Selected Yes", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You Un-selected Yes", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });

}
```

`Edit`

My Imports are :

`import android.app.Activity;`

`import android.os.Bundle;`

`import android.view.Menu;`

`import android.widget.CheckBox;`

`import android.widget.CompoundButton;`

`import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;// this one collides with`

`import android.widget.RadioGroup;`

`import android.widget.Toast;`

`import android.widget.RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener;// this one`

Now I'm unable to fix this please tell me what should I do.
Thanks in Advance...

Comment: Paste your imports, and also entire error message

Comment: Please share log if u r getting any error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two different OnCheckedChangeListeners, let the compiler know which version you want to use:

RadioGroup uses [`RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener.html):

```
radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
//                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

CheckBox uses [`CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener.html):

```
checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
//                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: You need to remove the conflicting import statements as well. Clean your project or press Ctrl+Shift+O to do this automatically.